# Shift register using dff verilog

Tags: verilog, flipflop, shift-register

[image]I want to create a shift register using d-flip-flop as basic structural element,
code:

dff:

```
  module dff(d,q,clk,rst);

  input d,clk,rst;
  output reg q;

  always @(posedge clk)
     begin:dff_block
        if(rst==1'b1)
          q=1'b0;
        else
          q=d;
     end
  endmodule
```

shift register:

```
  module shift_register(s1,d,clk,s0,q);
  parameter n=3;

  input  s1,clk;
  input [n:0] d;

  output s0;
  output [n:0] q;

  genvar i;

  assign d[3]=s1;


  generate
  for(i=0; i<=n; i=i+1)
     dff U1(.d(d[i]),.q(q[i]),.clk(clk));
  endgenerate

  assign q[3]=d[2];
  assign q[2]=d[1];
  assign q[1]=d[0];
  assign q[0]=s0;



  endmodule
```

test bench:

```
  module tb();

  parameter n=3;
  reg [n:0] d;
  reg s1,clk;

  wire [n:0] q;
  wire s0;


  shift_register UUT(.s1(s1),.d(d),.clk(clk),.q(q),.s0(s0));

  initial begin

  d=4'b0000;
  clk=0;
  end


always
begin:clok
#10 clk=~clk; s1=1;

end
endmodule
```

I think test bench has the problem.I have tried to give s1 values for every #10 while clk=1 but again does not work.

This code does not give me waveforms for q and s0.
I cant find whats wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Where the `rst` signals are connected? Looks like nowhere. Get them connected and assert global reset on the start of the simulation.

Comment: Nothing drives `s0` either.- you can see that as the blue (_hi-Z_) trace in your simulation.

Comment: Try to put the 4 continuous assigns inside of a always @(posedge clock) and remove the assigns and replace the equals with arrow equals <=

Comment: i need to do it with structural modeling

Comment: @ece None of the comments suggested otherwise

Comment: @EugeneSh., except the one by Vahe.

Comment: @ThePhoton Well, the `dff` has a behavioral model anyway.

Comment: In module dff, inside the always block, you used continuous assignment `=`; use non-blocking assignment `<=` instead so that the synthesis tool can correctly infer that you want memory.

Comment: Looks like this question was [cross-posted to SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53786735/shift-register-using-dff-verilog) and the OP has accepted an answer there.

Answer (score 1):

```
module shift_register(s1,d,clk,s0,q);
    ...
input  s1,clk;
    ...
output s0;
output [n:0] q;
```

s0 is output, but the value never assigned to s0 in your code.